# Swift - Firebase function signInWithEmail don't execute in the first call

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, completion

```
@IBAction func loginEmailButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email.text!, password: password.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                if let errCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!.code) {
                    switch errCode {
                    case .ErrorCodeInvalidEmail:
                        self.emailLoginStatus = "invalid email"
                    case .ErrorCodeUserDisabled:
                        self.emailLoginStatus = "User account disabled"
                    case .ErrorCodeWrongPassword:
                        self.emailLoginStatus = "Wrong Password"
                    case .ErrorCodeUserNotFound:
                        self.emailLoginStatus = "User not found"
                    case .ErrorCodeNetworkError:
                        self.emailLoginStatus = "Could not connect"
                    default:
                        self.emailLoginStatus = "Login Error"
                    }
                }
            }else{
                self.emailLoginStatus = "Logged"
            }
        })

        if self.emailLoginStatus == "Logged"{
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("emailLoginToSearchSegue", sender: self)
        }else{
            showAlert(emailLoginStatus)
        }

}
```

I did debug the code step by step and this is the situation: When I tap the `loginEmailButton` for the first time, the email and password parameters are set to `signInWithEmail` function, but this function doesn't execute (the next step on debug goes directly out of function without run the completion block).

Then the simulator shows the alert message without text, but if I close the alert and tap the `loginEmailButton` again, the `signInWithEmail` is executed correctly and shows the alert with the correct message. I even tried updating the Firebase pods but the problem still remains.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its asynchronous issue. **`signInWithEmail`** makes an asynchronous call to the server, meaning this call will be loaded in a different network thread, which takes some time to complete, but since your `performSegueWithIdentifier` is put outside the completionBlock so it get's executed even before sign In could be completed, But when you press your button next time your users had been previously been signed in from your first call, so it segues...

Just put the

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("emailLoginToSearchSegue", sender: self)
```

inside the `signInWithEmail` completionBlock().

```
@IBAction func loginEmailButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email.text!, password: password.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            if let errCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!.code) {
                switch errCode {
                case .ErrorCodeInvalidEmail:
                    self.emailLoginStatus = "invalid email"
                case .ErrorCodeUserDisabled:
                    self.emailLoginStatus = "User account disabled"
                case .ErrorCodeWrongPassword:
                    self.emailLoginStatus = "Wrong Password"
                case .ErrorCodeUserNotFound:
                    self.emailLoginStatus = "User not found"
                case .ErrorCodeNetworkError:
                    self.emailLoginStatus = "Could not connect"
                default:
                    self.emailLoginStatus = "Login Error"
                }
            }
        }else{
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("emailLoginToSearchSegue", sender: self)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Accept(Tick mark on the top left of my answer) this as answer if it solved your issue :) Happy Coding

Comment: Dravidian, your answer makes sense, thank you, but i had tried it before without success. If I put performSegueWithIdentifier inside the signInWithEmail function and tap the Login button, the segue is trigged without the signInWithEmail error verifications. It happens because the signInWithEmail function still not executes in the first call and now this function is hidding the performSegueWithIdentifier

Comment: But if err == nil then why would it need to do the error verification?