# Firebase Email Verification Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried to use the Firebase Authentication, but in the login lets me in even when I haven't used the email to confirm the verification.
I have two Viewcontroller , one for Login and the other for signUP.
I can log in and I get the email for verification, but I can also log in in without verification.

```
public func sendVerificationMail() {
  if self.authUser != nil && !self.authUser!.isEmailVerified {
    self.authUser!.sendEmailVerification(completion: { (error) in
      // Notify the user that the mail has sent or couldn't because of an error.
    })
  } else {
    // Either the user is not available, or the user is already verified.
  }
}

@IBAction func signupButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
  print("Sign up button tapped")
  Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.userEmailTextField.text!, password: self.userPasswordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in
    if user != nil {
      print("User has Signed Up")
      self.sendVerificationMail()    
    }
    if error != nil {
      print("User cant Sign Up")
    }
  }
}

@IBAction func signinButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
  Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.userEmailTextField.text!, password: self.userPasswordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in
    if user != nil {
      print("User has Signed In") 
    }
    if error != nil {
      print("Cant Sign in user")
    } else {
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toHome", sender: nil)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Auth doesn't prevent people from signing in when their email isn't verified. If you want to prevent users from advancing when they aren't verified, you will need to code this on the client using the `isEmailVerified` boolean.

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.userEmailTextField.text!, password: self.userPasswordTextField.text!) { (authResult, error) in
  if let authResult = authResult {
    let user = authResult.user
    print("User has Signed In")
    if user.isEmailVerified {
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toHome", sender: nil)
    } else {
      // do whatever you want to do when user isn't verified
    }
  }
  if let error = error {
    print("Cant Sign in user")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I Get an error

 Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'isEmailVerified'

Comment: I have updated my answer. I recommend you check out the [Firebase guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth) to find out more about Auth going forward.

Comment: This code is not safe, you should not force unwrap the optionals.

Answer (score 0):

A more comprehensive solution than that provided by @jen-person (and based on together with another SO answer) is this:

```swift
final class MySignInView: UIView { // or possibly MySignInViewController: UIViewController

    // ... your properties etc...

    @IBAction func signInButtonPressed(sender _: AnyObject) {
        trySigningIn()
    }

}

// MARK: Private
private extension MySignInView {

    func trySigningIn() {
        guard 
            let email = userEmailTextField.text,
            let password = userPasswordTextField.text
        else {
            print("Cannot sign in, email or password is 'nil'")
            return
        }

        do {
            try signIn(email: email, password: password) { [unowned self] authResult in
                self.userDidSignIn(authResult.user)
            }
        } catch {
            // Display error
        }
    }

    func userDidSignIn(_ user: FIRUser) {
        // Creds to Jen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51389154/1311272
        guard user.isEmailVerified else {
            // TODO display message about non verified email user?
            return
        }
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toHome", sender: nil)
    }
}

// MARK: Error
private extension MySignInView {
    enum Error: Strng, Equatable {
        case invalidEmail
        case userDisabled
        case wrongPassword
        case userNotFound
        case networkError
        case unknownError
    }
}

// MARK: Firebae specific
private extension MySignInView {

    func signIn(
        email: String, 
        password: String, 
        onSuccessful: (AuthDataResult) -> Void
    ) throws {

        Auth.auth().signIn(
            withEmail: email, 
            password: password
        ) { (authResult, anyError) in
            if let anyError = anyError {
                if let error = Error(anyError: anyError) {
                    throw error
                } else {
                    fatalError("Unsupported error: \(anyError)")
                }
            }
            onSuccessful(authResult)
        }
    }
}

private extension MySignInView.Error {

    init?(anyError: Swift.Error) {
        guard let authErrorCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: anyError.code) else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(fireBaseAuthErrorCode: authErrorCode)
    }

    // Creds goes to to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39936083/1311272
    init(fireBaseAuthErrorCode: FIRAuthErrorCode) {
        switch errCode {
        case .ErrorCodeInvalidEmail:
            self = .invalidEmail
        case .ErrorCodeUserDisabled:
            self = .userDisabled
        case .ErrorCodeWrongPassword:
            self = .wrongPassword
        case .ErrorCodeUserNotFound:
            self = .userNotFound
        case .ErrorCodeNetworkError:
            self = .networkError
        default:
            self = .unknownError
        }
    }
}
```

You need to inform the user appropriately about the different errors/incorrect states of course, not only print.

This code should probably me moved to a `ViewModel`, and if your are not using `MVVM`, I highly recommend it :).

Answer (score 0):

```
if let email = emailTextfield.text, let password = passwordTextfield.text {
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
    
    if let e = error{
        print(e.localizedDescription)
    }
    else {
        //Do whatever you want to do after successful login
        
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this also:

```
   if( !Auth.auth().currentUser!.isEmailVerified) {
    // do something
   }
```